# I want to copy different folders & a file in them (same for all folders) to another folder - unix

Tags: linux, shell, for-loop, copy, directory

Say I have multiple folders, with many files in each, but the file I'm interested in it is "xyz.p" :

~/home/A/xyz.p

~/home/B/xyz.p

~/home/C/xyz.p

~/home/D/xyz.p

Now I want to copy each of these folder with only one file from it "xyz.p" to another directory:

~/trial/A/xyz.p

~/trail/B/xyz.p

~/trail/C/xyz.p

~/trail/D/xyz.p

I do not want to copy the other files from folder A, B, C, D.

For now I've tried using for long for shell scripts but its not really working.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the easiest way to tackle this problem is to write a simple script.

```
#!/bin/bash

STARTDIR="home"
TARGETDIR="test"

FILENAME="xyz.p"

for DIR in 'A' 'B' 'C' 'D';
do
  cp -rfv $STARTDIR/$DIR/$FILENAME $TARGETDIR/$DIR/$FILENAME
done
```

This script takes the file from startdir/subdir and puts in into the targetdir/subdir directory.

The sub-directories can be put into the list in single quotes on the line of the for command.

The -rfv means that the copy will be recursive(include all subdirectories), forced, and verbose(tell you what it is doing).

The output for this script for me was

```
$./moveit.sh
`home/A/xyz.p' -> `test/A/xyz.p'
`home/B/xyz.p' -> `test/B/xyz.p'
`home/C/xyz.p' -> `test/C/xyz.p'
`home/D/xyz.p' -> `test/D/xyz.p'
```

Hope this was helpful.
Please try to do a little more research before asking though :)

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
parallel 'mkdir -p ~/trial/{//}; cp {} ~/trial/{//}' ::: */xyz.p
```

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to. It can often replace a `for` loop.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

If GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel